# AngularJS ng-show with ng-animate unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

The problem is that when I double click very quickly on a button to toggle an ng-show, the value will not change (this is expected behavior - it toggles) but the actual element will be hidden. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QbZrJ/

If you double click quickly, the value stays true, but the element fades out. If the ng-animate directive is removed, it works as expected, so I guess this has to do with the animation.

```
function ctrl($scope){
   $scope.foo = true;
   $scope.clicked = function(){
      $scope.foo = !($scope.foo);
   }
}
```

Nothing fishy there. Note that this is using the old way of animating in AngularJS but I observe the behavior in AngularJS 1.2.8 as well.

Edit: I think the animation duration is the issue after some troubleshooting. It seems that with 0 delay it works fine. With anything nonzero, it somehow ignores the fact that it should be hidden and completes the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you still use AngularJS **1.1.4**.

Since **1.2**, AngularJS uses a completely different API for animations.
Be aware that **ng-animate is a separate module** now, so you must include it in your scripts and also in your module dependencies list.

You can read more about it this article: [Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

#### Refactored to AngularJS 1.2 -> [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/hKV9v/)

#### html:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-animate.min.js">
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <div ng-click='clicked()'>[Double Click Me Fast] ng-show:{{foo}}</div>  
        <div ng-show="foo"  class='myDiv'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### js:

```js
angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.foo = true;
    $scope.clicked = function(){
       $scope.foo = !($scope.foo);
    }
  });
```

#### css:

```css
.myDiv{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity  1s linear;
   -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
   transition: opacity 1s linear;
   opacity: 1;
}

.myDiv.ng-hide-add, .myDiv.ng-hide-remove{
  display:block!important;
}
.myDiv.ng-hide{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately the bug still exists, so I've filed an issue for it.