# Why is ng-class based ng-animate transition not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ng-animate

This is a heavily simplified demo of `ng-class` animation using transition  that I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to create a simple fade in animation when an item is selected.

Selecting an item will add a `selected` class on it using `ng-class` directive. I'm trying to add a transition to it following the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations#class-and-ngclass-animation-hooks) with the animation hook classes added by `ng-animate`.

Below is the code I have so far. It sets the `opacity` to `0` along with the transition property, and when the `.selected-add-active` class is added it is supposed to transition to `opacity` 1. But it does not work.

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = false;
    $scope.selectToggle = function() {
      $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
  });
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}
.item.selected {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.item.selected.selected-add {
  transition: opacity 3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.item.selected.selected-add.selected-add-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-class="{selected:selected}"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="selectToggle();">
    {{selected? 'Unselect' : 'Select'}}
  </button>
</div>
```

Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the order in which angular ng-animate applies the CSS classes and how browser optimizes DOM reflows.

`ng-animate` initially adds the `x-add` class prior to actually adding class `x`. This is where it forces(or fakes) a DOM reflow so that browser detects the initial state for animation.

But since the selector for initial state's CSS (`.item.selected.selected-add`) is chained with `.selected` class which isn't added yet, it doesn't match anything and browser ignores it.

After this, `ng-animate` adds the `selected` class followed by `selected-add-active` class. At this point the CSS selector for initial state does match,  but these changes happens in the same reflow, hence the browser chooses to apply `opacity` from the selector with highest specificity which is

```
.item.selected.selected-add.selected-add-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Now since no actual change in the element's `opacity` is detected, no transition takes place.

---

To fix this, avoid chaining the animation hook classes added by `ng-animate` with the class being toggled. Especially the `x-add` class which should be detected by the browser before the following classes gets applied.

Below is a working example:

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = false;
    $scope.selectToggle = function() {
      $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };
  });
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}
.item.selected {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.item.selected-add {
  transition: opacity 3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.item.selected-add.selected-add-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-class="{selected:selected}"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="selectToggle();">
    {{selected? 'Unselect' : 'Select'}}
  </button>
</div>
```